# C++/CLI System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.' while converting System String into int

Tags: c++, c++-cli

I am making a mouse, I made it with my arduino, and I am sending the data (x,y, and if the button is pressed or not(my data looks like this : x234y256s0) through a serial port to a c++/cli console app (CLR). I successfully passed the data to cli, and I turned it that data into std::string, then I separated that string into 3 strings x,y and s, then I wanted to turn those  `std::strings` into ints, I first needed to turn them into System Strings (String^), that was also successful, and then I tried to turn it into ints like this: `int X = System::Convert::ToInt32(x1);` (will show my entire code later), that line gave me this error:

```
System.FormatException: 'Input string was not in a correct format.'
```

Also, I added this line at the end of my code `SetCursorPos(mouseX, mouseY);`, and that line gave me 2 errors:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A0001DE) "extern "C" int __stdcall SetCursorPos(int,int)" (?SetCursorPos@@$$J18YGHHH@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z) arduinoSerial2  C:\.....    1   and
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error   LNK2019 unresolved external symbol "extern "C" int __stdcall SetCursorPos(int,int)" (?SetCursorPos@@$$J18YGHHH@Z) referenced in function "int __clrcall main(cli::array<class System::String ^ >^)" (?main@@$$HYMHP$01AP$AAVString@System@@@Z)  arduinoSerial2  C:\.....    1   ,
```

I really don't know what this 2 errors mean, I never used CLI before, and I use c++ very rarely.

```
#include "pch.h"
//#include <user32.lib>

#include <string>

using namespace System::IO::Ports;

#include <msclr\marshal_cppstd.h>
int main(array<System::String^>^ args)
{
    int mouseX = 0;
    int mouseY = 0;
    SerialPort port("COM3", 9600);
    port.Open();
    while (true) {
        System::String^ data = gcnew System::String(port.ReadLine());
        /*array<wchar_t>^ id = { 'x' ,'y' };
         array<String^>^ x = data->Split(id);*/
        std::string data1 = msclr::interop::marshal_as<std::string>(data);

        int firstX = data1.find('x') + 1;
        int lastX = data1.find('y');
        std::string x = data1.substr(firstX, lastX - firstX);
        System::String^ x1 = gcnew System::String(x.c_str());

        int firstY = data1.find('y') + 1;
        int lastY = data1.find('s');
        std::string y = data1.substr(firstY, lastY - firstY);
        System::String^ y1 = gcnew System::String(y.c_str());

        int firstS = data1.find('s') + 1;
        //int lastS = data1.find('y');
        std::string s = data1.substr(firstS);
        System::String^ s1 = gcnew System::String(s.c_str());



        //System::Console::WriteLine(x1);
        int X = System::Convert::ToInt32(x1);
        int Y = System::Convert::ToInt32(y1);
        int SW = System::Convert::ToInt32(s1);
        if (SW == 0) {
            //click

        }
        if (X >= 400) {
            //up
            mouseX += 1;
        }
        if (X <= 150) {
            //down
            mouseX -= 1;
        }
        if (Y >= 400) {
            //right 
            mouseY += 1;
        }
        if (X <= 150) {
            //left
            mouseY -= 1;
        }
        SetCursorPos(mouseX, mouseY);

    }
    return 0;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try: `int i = int::Parse(str); // string to int`

Comment: I still get the same error, it doesn't work at all if I put a std::string in Parse, and when I put System String in it, I get the same error that I got with ToInt. Thank you anyway